# Is there a way to get the url of the header image (og:image) of an external URL using LPMetadataProvider?

Tags: ios, swift

I know that you can fetch metadata using LPMetadataProvider, and you can get the title of an article from the metadata. But can you get the link of the header image?

```
let metadataProvider = LPMetadataProvider()
let url = URL(string: "https://www.apple.com/ipad")!

metadataProvider.startFetchingMetadata(for: url) { metadata, error in
    if error != nil { return }

    // trying to get the image url from metadata
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the answer is no. You can only get the actual image. URL images may change and I believe that the idea is not to have cached image URLs.

Comment: Why would it be a cached image URL? Isn't the startFetchingMetadata(for: url) running a a request to the url, which then could parse contents for the header image url?

Comment: I was saying they most likely don’t want people caching image URLs. The metadata, as it stands, will only give you an image, if there is one. I wish it did give an image url, but it doesn’t.